# How to record the video with overlay images using Avfoundation framework

Tags: ios

Using AVFoundation I need to capture or record the video where not only camera output but also overlay images and text also should be recorded. I have seen lots of example to add the  image to camera preview but what i want is not only overlay image or text preview but actual recording of the overlay in the final video output.